# How to contact spring-cloud-loadbalancer team?

Tags: spring-cloud-loadbalancer

How can someone report issue/get attention for spring-cloud-loadbalancer project? Jira/forum/mailing list/whatever? If they are under spring-cloud how to contact them? There does not seem to be any contact made public anywhere...

Comment: simply excellent.